# create ROS package using code blocks: export cflags and lflags return nothing

Tags: package, codeblocks, ros

I want to use CodeBlocks to create a ros package and I followed [the tutorials in ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#CodeBlocks). The second step is to get the cflags and lflags of the dependent packages used in the new package.

However, when I tried to use the command `rospack export --lan=cpp --att=cflags packagename`, it returns an empty line.

Could any one tell me how to get those flags or how to use code blocks to create ROS package?

Thanks!